# jQuery -- loading a menu from a file -- always a list, never a menu

Tags: jquery, menu, load

I would like to be able to load menus from html files and have them function as menus. The text will load, but alas, it always appear as simple lists -- menu and submenu choices all visible -- instead of menus.

Here is shortmenu.html, one of my test files:

```
<ul id="menuChap">
<li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Item 3-1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item 3-2</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is the simplest of attempted scripts, complete with a meaningless token action :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

      $('#menuDiv').load('shortmenu.html');

      $('#menuChap').menu({
           select: function(event, ui){
                alert("Pushed!");
           }
      });
 });
```

Here's another one with a time-wasting alert to make sure the load is done before moving on to other tasks:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

      $('#menuDiv').load('shortmenu.html', function() {
           alert("Load is finished");
      });

      $('#menuChap').menu({
           select: function(event, ui){
                alert("Pushed!");
           }
      });
 });
```

Here's another with that new-fangled .on function:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

      $('#menuDiv').on('click', function(e) { 
           e.preventDefault(); 
           $('#menuDiv').load('shortmenu.html'); 
           alert("Load is finished");
      });

      $('#menuChap').menu({
           select: function(event, ui){
                alert("Pushed!");
           }
      });
 });
```

and instead of a functioning menu, all I ever get is a list-y lump that looks like this:

```
 * Item 1
 * Item 2
 * Item 3
      * Item 3-1
      * Item 3-2
      * Item 3-3
      * Item 3-4
 * Item 4
 * Item 5
```

So what am I not seeing? Can anyone here point me to a good working example or clue me in?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
$(function() {
      $('#menuDiv').load('shortmenu.html', function() {
          $('#menuChap').menu({
              select: function(event, ui){
                alert("Pushed!");
              }
          });
      });
});
```

Ajax calls are asynchronous, so your `.menu()` call needs to wait until the `.load()` has finished. In this overload, the second parameter is the callback method for when the response is complete.